# Jquery not() select is not working in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to exclude the click even when user click on the .special, but it doesn't seem work?

```
<body>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p class="special">special</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
</body>
```

my js

```
    $("body:not(.special)").click(function () {
        alert('test');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vv9L1eog/1/

Comment: `$('body')` selects the elements with the `<body>` tag. Selecting the body tags without the class `.special` does not do much, as no such tags exists. You should target the paragraphs, as in `$('body p:not(.special)')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `":not"` filter with p not with body.

```
$("body p:not(.special)").click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

**EDIT:**

For clicking anywhere on the page

```
$("body").click(function () {
                alert('test');
            }).find(".special").click(function(){return false;});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsss/vv9L1eog/6/)

Comment: but I want to do alert() when user click everywhere on my page.

Comment: this will also ensure click event will not apply to every element inside body. Happy Coding.

Comment: the second code is interesting.. but will the find() have performances issue?

Answer (score 3):

Space between `body` and `:not`. It means it select its successors.

```
$("body :not(.special)").click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vv9L1eog/2/

**Update: alert in the whole page except special DOM**

You need to bind on `html` instead of `body` when you mean *whole page*.

```
$("html").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.special')) {
        console.log(e.target);
        alert('test');
     }
});
```

Besides, your `<p>` tag is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). The *special* DOM in your example is the *whole row* in the page.

If you want to only disable click on the special *text*, wrap your text to a [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente). As:

```
<body>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p><span class="special">special</span></p>
    <p>normal</p>
    <p>normal</p>
</body>
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vv9L1eog/7/

Comment: but I want to do alert() when user click everywhere on my page.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$('html').click(function(e) {
    if (! $(e.target).is('.special') ) {
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

This will prompt you an alert when clicking anywhere on the page.

Comment: but I want to do alert() when user click everywhere on my page.

Answer (score 0):

You selectors are slightly out,

try:

```
$("body :not(.special)").click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/3q0kLr5w/1/

```
        $("body").children().not('.special').click(function () {
            alert('test');
        });
```

or even 
            $("body *:not(.special)").click(function () {
                alert('test');
            });

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off attaching a single click handler to the body, and test the `event.target` to check whether it is `.special` or not:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if (! $( e.target ).is('.special') ) {
         alert( 'test' );
    }
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/vv9L1eog/5/)